# Finding source of unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Chaining cycle detected for promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, v8

I'm trying to find the source of an unhandled rejection from a Promise in Node.js

I've tried upgrading to Node version 12, using the `--async-stack-traces` option, and listening for them using:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection",( reason, promise ) => {
  console.log(reason);
  console.log(promise);
});
```

But I still don't see any helpful stack trace to help me find the culprit!

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Chaining cycle detected for promise #<Promise>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:89675) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 11)
```

Running Node v10.10.0

Comment: Are there multiple promises?

Comment: The error in **your** code is a cyclic chaining, like you would have with `const cyclic = Promise.resolve().then(()=>cyclic);`, so don't search for an unhandled promise rejection, this one is in node's internal code.

Comment: Some code rising the issue would be helpful.

Comment: running `npm i bluebird` and adding `const Promise = require('bluebird')` to the code may give you a more detailed error message

Comment: try to run node with `--trace-warnings`, unhandled rejections are accompanied with  warnings that you can trace

Comment: Did you try `console.dir(reason)` or `console.log(reason.stack)`? Maybe you can't see the entire stack

Comment: Your question has conflicting information.  You state "I've tried upgrading to Node version 12" and "Running Node v10.10.0"

Comment: Sounds like you need to remember the basics: create an [mcve], moreso for you than for us. Remove any code hat isn't relevant to the codepath that leads to your error, and start hardcoding things like dynamic lookups so you can throw away entire functions or even classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the suggestions. I've tried once more by upgrading to the latest Node `12.14.1` and was finally able to get it to show the stack trace:

I used `node --async-stack-traces myScript.js` in conjunction with:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log(reason);
});
```

And it tracked down the error.

Comment: Doesn't node 12 log the unhandled rejection reason even without that event handler?

Comment: Haven’t you even try the solution I have provided ?

Answer (score 2):

If you miss an helpful stacktrace, you can make node create a new one by re-throwing your error in your handler like this:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => { throw reason });
```

This way, you should be able to track down the culprit.

Comment: I just try again on my side, and it definitely works.

Comment: @d-_-b have you been able to test this on your side?

Comment: Hi @Gomino, yes unfortunately it didn't work in my scenario but I appreciate your help here!

Answer (score -1):

To find some good stack trace for this code
`const cyclic = Promise.resolve().then(() => cyclic);`
I put this code into the file `prromise_cycle.js` and run with inspector to debug it.

I debug it on Chrome DevTools with flag `Pause on caught exceptions` enabled, and then I can see the whole stack trace with my file on it

[image]